# Как сделать так, что ActionBar не показывался на экране?

Tags: java, android

Я делаю `popUp`, мне просто необходимо, чтоб выскакивала своего рода всплывающая подсказка с коротким описанием. Я это делаю с помощью создания активити и задаю ему размеры и вроде как получается то, что я хочу. Но проблема в том, что как и у любого активити у него есть `actionBar` который смотрится не кстати))

В общем вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал вот такую строчку добавлять

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

--->>    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);
```

но ничего не меняется абсолютно...

Подскажите как это сделать? Тем более я знаю, что это широко используется в играх, так как там каждый миллиметр экрана важен...

Я кстати не знаю имеет ли это значение или нет, но у меня андроид 5.0

Пробовал создать свой стиль вот так

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomStyle">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

и вот так присваиваю его в манифесте

```
 <activity android:name=".Pop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomStyle"
        ></activity>
```

Но ничего не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создайте стиль для активити.
2. Пропишите в нём

   ```
   <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   ```
3. Присвойте его активити либо в манифесте, либо в коде **до** вызова `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

---

Так же может помочь установка класса актвити на расширение Activity вместо AppCompatActivity

Comment: Я внес правку в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста что я сделал не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, попробуйте родителя стилю задать. В зависимости от того какой класс расширяет активити это может быть `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` или `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.`

Comment: Все получилось...)) деиствительно проблема была в том, что мое активити расширял класс `AppCompatActivity` когда я поменял на `Activity` то все заработало)) я даже не знал, что это как то влияет... Добавте это в свой ответ, может кому еще это пригодиться, и я отмечу как правильный

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, дополнил ответ. Хотя вы и сами можете вносить правки в любые ответы и я думаю, что и для AppCompatActivity должно сработать)